# Exclude future dates in a multi results select

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, select

I have two tables:

- tv shows (which contains an unique_id and a popularity index)
- tv episodes related to tv shows

Now what I would like to do is: extract the top 10 tv shows (by popularity index) that has at least one episode aired in the past month (what I'm trying to obtain is a trending list).

What I'm doing is:

```
SELECT 
     tvshows.name,
     tvshows.popularity,
     MAX(episodes.air_date) as last_air_date
 FROM
      tvshows,
      episodes
 WHERE
       tvshows.id = episodes.show_id
 GROUP BY 
     tvshows.id
 HAVING
     last_air_date BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

But it's not working because of the MAX function because there are shows, currently airing (even in this month), but that also have episodes set to air in far future (failing the condition of the last month).

Can anybody please help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about filtering out the future shows in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT 
     tvshows.name,
     tvshows.popularity,
     MAX(episodes.air_date) as last_air_date
 FROM
      tvshows
 JOIN episodes
   ON tvshows.id = episodes.show_id
 WHERE  episodes.air_date <= CURRENT_DATE()
 GROUP BY 
     tvshows.id
 HAVING
     last_air_date BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

Note, if your `air_date` includes time, then comparing it to `CURRENT_DATE()` will exclude shows that air today after midnight. I also updated your `JOIN` syntax, while yours works, it's been deprecated for many years.

Comment: Holy shiet, didn't think of that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but something like this should do

```
    SELECT top 10
         tvshows.id,
         tvshows.name,
         tvshows.popularity,
         MAX(episodes.air_date) as last_air_date
     FROM
          tvshows,
          episodes
     WHERE
           tvshows.id = episodes.show_id
           and episodes.air_date BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()
     GROUP BY 
         tvshows.id,
         tvshows.name,
         tvshows.popularity
     order by popularity desc
```